# German text in everyshipout hook

Tags: pdftex, miktex

I have an everyshipout hook -

```
%preamble
\documentclass[german]{article}
. . .
\newcommand\MYEveryShipout{}
\EveryShipout{\MYEveryShipout}

% body
\renewcommand{\MYEveryShipout}{%
    SomeSpecialText=äöüÄÖÜß;
}
```

The text `äöüÄÖÜß` appears as `aouAOUs`.

Do I Need to do something extra to get encodings to work in an EveryShipout hook?

Comment: @NormanGray Thanks - actually I just realized I could also use "AtEveryPageHook" and get what I want. If I have the time I'll compare the two to see what's different.

Comment: Why a -1? Can someone explain?

Comment: In general, questions can be downvoted because someone judged that the question was not good (question not stated properly, not corresponding to topic of the SE, MWE missing, ...).

Comment: I asked only because if I know the reason why someone doesn't think the question is so great (and voted it down) I would have the chance to edit the question and make it better for everyone. So, if there is something unclear or not on Topic, etc. here - I'd like the chance to make an improvement.

Comment: I understand. I just answered in general. I do not understand either why your question was downvoted. I also prefer to be informed about possible problems with my questions, so I can improve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in my comment above, replace "EveryShipOut" with "AtEveryPageHook."
I don't know why one handles the german text and not the other.

If someone else can explain it, I'd be perfectly glad to Transfer answer Status - if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you use other packages in your preambles, so perhaps the problem is that you have packages missing. These work for me in documents in German language and allow proper umlauts and ß:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[german]{babel}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    ...
```

Comment: Hello Javier, I overlooked your answer. The packages you suggest are already there. What I noticed, as in my comment to Norman Gray, is that I can use "AtEveryPageHook" instead of EveryShipOut and get what I want. Why "EveryShipOut" doesn't handle the german text is still a mystery - I havn't had time to look into it.