# Using \EveryShipout corrupts the copyable text

Tags: pdf, copy-paste, textpos, accessibility, everyshi

This is a strange bug. I'm using the `textpos` package (which in turn uses the `everyshi` package) to place text at a certain position on the page. Consider this document:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Renderer=HarfBuzz,Script=Devanagari]{Chandas}

\begin{document}

% package textpos uses \paperheight and \paperwidth
\paperheight=1561bp
\paperwidth=1044bp
\TPGrid{1044}{1561}
\begin{textblock}{200}(173,213)
added later किं  बहुना । परस्परं द्वैधम् उत्पन्नम् । added later
\end{textblock}

Some text.
\newbox\foo
\setbox\foo=\vbox{\hbox{boxed किं  बहुना । परस्परं द्वैधम् उत्पन्नम् । boxed}}

inline किं  बहुना । परस्परं द्वैधम् उत्पन्नम् । and also below
\unvbox\foo

\end{document}
```

(The [Chandas font is from here](http://www.sanskritweb.net/cakram/).) The [resulting PDF](https://shreevatsa.net/post/add-ocr-layer-to-pdf/everyshi-problem.pdf) looks like:

[image: result]

The Devanagari text is the same in all three places. As in my previous question [Getting correct searchable text for Devanagari text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562453/getting-correct-searchable-text-for-devanagari-text), everything works fine (when compiled with `lualatex` from Tex Live 2020: [see on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/djbrkhhwqqyq)) i.e. selecting and copying text from the PDF gives correct results, for the inline text and for the manually unvboxed text,

> inline किं बहुना । परस्परं द्वैधम् उत्पन्नम्। and also below

> boxed किं बहुना । परस्परं द्वैधम् उत्पन्नम्। boxed

but for the text added later with `textpos`, I get:

> added later ��� बहु�� । परस्पर� ��ध�� उत्पन्न�� । added later

What could be the reason? Is there a fix?

Comment: I see [a previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344696/german-text-in-everyshipout-hook) that *may* be related, but it has no details and it is at -1 and the OP's answer mentions `AtEveryPageHook` which as far as I can tell doesn't exist and probably cannot be used for this use-case anyway.

Comment: Looks like [`everyshi`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ms/everyshi.pdf) is only 32 lines of well-motivated and self-contained code...

Comment: I see no difference in the copy&paste behaviour. Unrelated: everyshi will be replaced by kernel code in the next latex release. The textpos code is currently *not* compatible and will break. The maintainer has been informed some weeks ago, but I don't know when he will update.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for taking a look…. Do you get broken results in both cases or are both fine? I've [uploaded the resulting PDF](https://shreevatsa.net/post/add-ocr-layer-to-pdf/everyshi-problem.pdf) (from "This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020)" on macOS); are your results different?

Comment: I see now a difference, but only in adobe reader. But I see also the difference in the pdf code. I need to discuss this with  Marcel.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, glad to know it's not just my system. Hopefully the reason can be found/fixed. Meanwhile I found a workaround by specifying the ActualText manually, as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171328/how-to-produce-unicode-copyable-alternative-text-with-accsupp/171335#171335) — maybe there's a simpler way now, but that worked for me.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Just curious, did you discuss / did anything come out of this? Wondering whether there's a bug somewhere and whether there's an easier workaround now…

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah I see there was some discussion [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55529174#55529174)… but I'm not sure of the conclusion. Anyway the workaround seems to work for me for now, so it's not a major problem for me. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: yes, we discussed it, and there is also already some code to extend the latex hooks, but we need to add it to the development version.Btw: setting box 255 doesn't work in a current latex. Better use the latex shipout hooks instead of this low-level manipulations.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh that's good to know, thanks. (Also I wasn't setting box255 manually actually but this MWE was from unwrapping what the `textpos` package was doing… I guess it too must have been updated now.)

Comment: the pull request (at least some part of discussion) it here https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/pull/396

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Looks like the above pull request was merged in January, so maybe this is fixed in TeX Live 2021. Haven't tested it yet though.

Comment: Your example no longer compiles as you can't use box 255, but if I replace 255 by \ShipoutBox all text copies fine (but you should better not use everyshi but the shipout hooks instead).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks that's great to know! As I had mentioned earlier, I was using `textpos` and had replaced it with `everyshi` for debugging before asking the question, so I edited the question just now to use the original syntax I had been using. I guess `textpos` has also been updated now and will no longer have the error (all text will copy fine). Thank you! Could you post that as an answer so that I can accept it and get this question off the Unanswered list?